# Deleting a document via sharepoint web service using JQuery

Tags: jquery, web-services, sharepoint

I am trying to delete a document, using the sharepoint webservice, if someone uploads a document and then hits cancel. I have created the following function

```
    function DeleteDocument(libraryName, ID)
{
debug.log('DeleteDocument (Entry) libraryname = '+libraryName+' ID='+ID);
    var batch =
        "<Batch OnError='Continue'> \
            <Method ID='1' Cmd='Delete'> \
                <Field Name='ID'>" + ID + "</Field> \
            </Method> \
        </Batch>";

    var soapEnv =
        "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> \
        <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' \
xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' \
xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
          <soap:Body> \
            <UpdateListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
              <listName>"+libraryName+"</listName> \
              <updates> \
                " + batch + "</updates> \
            </UpdateListItems> \
          </soap:Body> \
        </soap:Envelope>";
    debug.log(soapEnv);
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://<serverandsite>/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction",
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems");
        },
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: function(xData, status){          
            alert(xData.responseText);
            debug.log('xData response = ' + xData.responseText);
            debug.log('status response = ' + status);
        },
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
    });
}
```

When i run it i get

> 0x81020030 - Invalid file name
>
> The file name you specified could not
>   be used.  It may be the name of  an
>   existing file or directory, or you may
>   not have permission to  access the
>   file.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be failing. I am running the code against a standard document library.

I have tried it against checked-in and checked out files and get the same message. I need this to run against documents that are checked out, in fact they will never have been checked in, so i have no idea how i could work out the fileref

Comment: Just to add i have just tried forcing a  <Field Name="FileRef"> element and this produces the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For documents you also need to include the FileRef

```
<Field Name="FileRef">http://Server/[sites/][Site/]Library/File</Field>
```

Comment: Ok, what i might do i write a small web service that taks in the ID and list name and then use the object model to take over the checkout and then delete the file.

Comment: I ended up deleting the document via an event handler but this should work